# typing toPrimitives interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an interface like this:

```
interface AggregateRoot<Primitives> {
  toPrimitives(): { [key in keyof Primitives]: any }
}
```

And I implement it like this:

```
class Person implements AggregateRoot<Person> {
  public name
  public age

  toPrimitives(): { [key in keyof Person]: any } {
    return {
      name: 'Tom',
      age: 10
    }
  }
}
```

This also forces me to return the key "toPrimitives"

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the return type to exclude any function types:

```
interface AggregateRoot<Primitives> {
  toPrimitives(): { 
    [K in keyof Primitives as Primitives[K] extends Function ? never : K]: any 
  }
}
```

```
toPrimitives(): { 
  [key in keyof Person as Person[key] extends Function ? never : key]: any 
} {
  return {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 10
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIHN1QuukBKA9oWADwAKUwAtsGMAG4QDOAfMgN4BQyyYhlGnUYsAFAEoAXJ2QBtANLJQyANYQAnoRjJBtek2bI4h3cIMKAusggAPSCAAmhgGIBXEAnqEQyAPzIQCCYoZGl5C2k4EHVkAF8ueK4EABtjE2hmbyVqAAdkiGoIcEMMLBw8CCISCgzvdm5eHNcAI2TgBAC4QoBCaWYwKhB0HmQm1vajdAhegNdqZuguEf5TfTEpGVk1GOVtrR1an2MDqEyQLY0rW3snZDcPLx9-QODQ1UvI6LjOEd5sMFcUB8DV4oJAXQg0gA5AAVQjUKEAGl%20oLgU2kAEYAAwo%20K8eKxIA)